# Capturar touch o click en una imagen(asset) con libGDX

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

resulta que estoy trabajando en un videojuego con libGDX en Android Studio y quiero capturar el click o touch a una imagen en especifico, encontré por ahí un método que caputra el click cuando presionas presionas cualquier lugar de la pantalla. Este es el código que encontré para dicho método ...

```
        `@Override
public void HandleInput() {

    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
        dispose();
    }
}`
```

Ese captura el click de toda la pantalla pero yo solo quiero que capture una imagen de esa pantalla en especifico... Hay algún método para que eso sea posible? o podría usar ese mismo método cambiándole algo? Si alguien me ayuda le estaría completamente agradecido :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias utilizar `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image`

A esta imagen le puedes añadir un `Listener` fácilmente

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen{
   private Stage stage;
   private Texture textura;
   private Imagen imagen;

   @Override
   public void create(){
       textura = new Texture("play.png");

       Image      imagen = new Image(textura);
       imagen.setSize(200,40);// aqui le ponemos un tamaño
       imagen.setPosition(50,50);//aquí le asignamos la posición


       imagen.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                //AQUI PONES LO QUE QUIERAS QUE PASE CUANDO SE APRIETE LA IMAGEN
                gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
                dispose();
            }
        });


       stage = new Stage();

       stage.add(imagen); // Añadimos la imagen al stage

       Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); //Le decimos a libgdx que este stage va ser el responsable de manejar el input
   }

   @Override 
   public void render(){
       stage.act(); //actualizamos el stage
       stage.draw();//dibujamos el stage
   }

   @Override 
   public void dispose(){
       stage.dispose();
       textura.dispose();
   }
}
```